# DB2 COUNT does not give correct number of rows

Tags: sql, count, db2

I have a large table, with 4,670,699,064 rows. When I loaded the table into db2, I tried to verify that I have the correct number of rows by

```
db2 "select count(*) from <schema>.<table_name>"
```

However, it only gave me 375,731,768 rows.

Then, as suggested by my colleague, I used COUNT_BIG as

```
db2 "select COUNT_BIG(*) from <schema>.<table_name>"
```

This time, it returns the correct number of rows.

Why couldn't I get 375,731,768 rows in the first attempt? [DB2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008469.html) says "The range of large integers is -2 147 483 648 to +2 147 483 647". Shouldn't I get 2,147,483,647 in the first attempt if the number of rows exceeded the max integer? Is it machine dependent?

Comment: That's how integer overflow "works".

Comment: 4,670,699,064 is bigger than 2,147,483,647 so any result you get is undefined.  What is your question?  Why DB2 does not give you the largest size on an overflow?  It just won't.

Comment: I don't know how did you get that value. In fact, the select fails and returns this message: SQL0802N  Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred.

SQLSTATE=22003